# How do I search for a file or directory in Ubuntu Server?

Tags: server, filesystem, files, search

It's often that I need to locate the path to files and directories in Ubuntu Server. Are there any good way to search for files or directories in the filesystem by name?

Comment: Have you tried the locate command? Just checking, because this question sounds too easy...

Comment: @nick: I have tried that now but it wasn't working as I expected, see my comment to the posted answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You name it: `locate`!

`locate` is a program installed by default that let you search for files/dirs by name, into its database updated with a cron job.

Go through the man page to see other interesting options, like regex search.

Moreover, you can use `find` to search on the current content of the filesystem (not on a database), with a full set of complicated options, that let you refine your search also based on metadata (permissions, modification time, etc.).

Comment: I installed a package to PostgreSQL using `apt-get install postgresql-contrib-8.4` but I don't know where it is installed and I can't find it using `locate contrib` or `locate *contrib*`.

Comment: so, use `locate postgresql`, after having updated the db (`sudo updatedb`) if required. Remember, it is not updated instantly after each filesystem modification. The `contrib` keyword is not a so happy choice.

Comment: @enzotib: `locate postgresql` doesn't work well for me, I only get `/etc/bash_completion.d/postgresql` as result.

Comment: @Jonas looking at the file list, it is located in /usr/share/postgresql/8.4/contrib/. Try "locate contrib/"

Comment: @nick: Thanks, that path seem to be correct, but I can't find it using `locate contrib/` it just give me a list of other directories but none of them are related to PostgreSQL.

Comment: @Jonas: as I said, have you update the `locate` db with `sudo updatedb`?

Comment: @Jonas Yeah, the dir might not have been indexed yet.

Comment: @enzotib: Thanks, now does `locate postgresql` work, but how often am I supposed to run `sudo updatedb`? I installed PostgreSQL a long time ago.

Comment: @Jonas: it is updated daily (in `/etc/cron.daily/mlocate`). You can update it manually when you need.

Comment: @enzotib: but it was many days since I installed PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 7):

The command `find / -name "name-to-search-for"` seem to work fine. A good thing was to add a `*` in the end or at the beginning of the name.

E.g. `find / -name "postgresql*"` list files and directories that starts with "postgresql".

Answer (score 1):

If you are installing and want to know what files you install... you can do that immediately following an install by doing the following:

```
touch marker
find <directorypath> -newer marker
```

There are some situations in which you will get results other than the newly installed applications(s):

- if Firefox or another browser is running there may be updated files
- if Virtualbox or other virtualization guest is running its virtual disk file may have been altered.

This method should work with installs from .deb files or scripted installs.

**NOTE:**

- **Do not use this from the 'root' directory as there are many system files that are updated frequently.**

Answer (score 0):

According to your comments, you are not looking for specific filenames but for files that belong to a package.
To see which files are associated with your installed package just type:

`dpkg -L postgresql-contrib-8.4`

Comment: @Jonas: also, update your question, in particular the title. If not pertinent, i will delete my answer.

Comment: @enzotib: No, the question is how I search for files (not only in this situation).

Comment: Thanks for this command, but I wan't to learn how to search for files by name, so this command only help me in this specific situation.